# Search query from multiple fields SQL LIKE Clause In MySQL

Tags: mysql

When I run this query it's not working

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_skill` WHERE `skill_name` LIKE '%PHP%Asp%'
```

[image: this is database table]

Comment: Whats is your desire result?

Comment: SELECT * FROM tbl_skill WHERE skill_name LIKE '%PHP%' OR skill_name LIKE '%Asp%'

Comment: want both row result

Comment: then try Waffles solution it works

Comment: yes but it will come in array sir @Waffles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [RLIKE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp), example:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_skill WHERE skill_name RLIKE 'PHP|Asp';
```

Comment: @RaviKharinta glad it helped :)

Comment: @RaviKharinta if this answer has solved your problem, please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) it and also give it an  up-vote.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the LIKE operator like an or operator.

for each LIKE term you need to have an additional OR for other searches.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_skill WHERE skill_name LIKE '%PHP%' OR skill_name LIKE '%Asp%'
```

If you don't want an array...

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_skill WHERE skill_name LIKE ANY(ARRAY['%PHP%','%Asp%'])
```

Comment: yes it work fine but it pass by parameter and in which array are come so how do this

Comment: I'm not understanding what you're asking.